# Cannot find module build.js while installing fibers with node.js

Tags: windows, node.js, node-fibers

I am extremely new to Node and my decision to try/start using it is the Meteor Framework. I installed it on OSX first, and it all works fine. But I would like it to work on another machine which is using Windows.

I use a MSI package that seems to install Node and Meteor nicely. They are installed on my %HOMEDRIVE% which is on "D:" (I don't think it matters but who knows...), and everything is in D:\Meteor.

I created a new app, started it but got an error... and later I found out that the issue was with fibers and people usually npm uninstall it and npm install it again, then it works. Well, this is where my issue is: the installation doesn't work at all. So here is what I get when I try installing fibers:

```
D:\Meteor\lib>npm install fibers
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fibers
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fibers

> fibers@0.6.8 install D:\Meteor\lib\node_modules\fibers
> node ./build.js

module.js:337
    throw new Error("Cannot find module '" + request + "'");
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'D:\build.js'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:337:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Array.0 (module.js:484:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:190:38)

npm ERR! fibers@0.6.8 install: `node ./build.js`
npm ERR! `cmd "/c" "node ./build.js"` failed with 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@0.6.8 install script.
```

I tried installing different packaged and it works. I have only this issue with fibers. Any idea how can I debug this? I have no idea where to look (I even failed to find the module.js...). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this still happen with the new Meteor 0.5.0? Since early Augustus some fixes have landed.

Comment: I've tried on node v.1.10.30, v4.4.3 and v5.10.1, separately trying the node-gyp suggestion as well as uninstalling/installing fibers separately, to no avail. I can't latest Meteor to install on Windows either.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix the problem by this command:

```
npm install -g node-gyp
```